# How do I make the Enter key on intellisense when typeing in VB react the same way as in C# in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 and I'm used to C# where when Intellisense pops up, I select what I want by hitting enter and it doesn't skip down to the next line. In VB when I hit the enter on intellisense, I jump to the next line. Does anyone know where the setting for this intellisense option might be?

Comment: possible duplicate of [VB.NET IntelliSense : Disable newline on ENTER autocomplete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977333/vb-net-intellisense-disable-newline-on-enter-autocomplete)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hitting the SPACEBAR or TAB key in VB does the same thing that ENTER does in C#.

Comment: Even though I know that TAB does the same as ENTER in C#, I still press ENTER constantly out of habit. I really wish you could configure this.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this doesn't really answer your question, but intellisense is designed to work so that you just push the "next" character to choose the highlighted item (such as open parenthesis, period, semi-colon, etc).

Answer (score 1):

I was bothered by this behavior in VB as well. This will be fixed in the next version of Visual Studio with a new setting for enter-key behavior.
<strike>https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/11873</strike>
Corrected link: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/11769

Comment: how does that link relate to either the question or your answer?

Comment: Oops. I meant to link to the change to Visual Studio that solves the problem described in the question.
Here's the correct link: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/11769
Sorry for the confusion.