# Disabling Intellisense Auto Line Return

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, intellisense

When I'm selecting an option from the IntelliSense list of options in a VB file, the editor will automatically enter my selection along with whichever keystroke I used to make my choice.  This is not something I'm used when using the ENTER to and honestly don't want to get used to since I don't anticipate doing a lot of VB work in the future.

I've already found the SPACEBAR/TAB option, also mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417625/how-do-i-make-the-enter-key-on-intellisense-when-typeing-in-vb-react-the-same-wa), but I'm dissatisfied with this solution, as the ENTER key is second nature for me. Isn't there any way to make the ENTER key simply make the selection and stay on the same line?