# When selecting something in VB with code-assist, I don't want VS10 to make a new line

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, settings

Usually I code C# in VS10, but I have to code a small program in VB.NET in VS10.

And I am used to selecting something with code-assist with Enter, but now in VB Enter also make a new line, which is very annoying because I can't help doing that all the time.

How can I turn this off/on so it's like when I code C#? I have looked, but could not find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant, you have to get used Tab or Space.

Comment: :( Can anybody confirm? I would hate to surrender this one to quickly

Comment: Yup, you're pretty much stuck with it. Here are a few more threads on the subject: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vbide/thread/4d384e0c-0a1e-486a-9751-0958bf1f3db9  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417625/how-do-i-make-the-enter-key-on-intellisense-when-typeing-in-vb-react-the-same-wa