# VB.NET IntelliSense : Disable newline on ENTER autocomplete

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

When editing C# code in Visual Studio 2010, the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key makes IntelliSense complete the current suggestion, without adding a new line.

In VB.NET, the default IntelliSense behavior for the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key is to add a new line after completing the current suggestion.

How can I configure IntelliSense to change the VB.NET behavior to the C# one?

I already know that I could press <kbd>TAB</kbd> or <kbd>SPACE</kbd>, but out of habit I always end up hitting <kbd>ENTER</kbd> (and changing line).

Comment: Get used to use TAB instead of ENTER

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Unfortunately the set of trigger keys for intellisense completion is not a configurable item for VB.Net.  There is no way in the default Visual Studio environment to change this behavior.

It would be possible to develop a plugin of sorts to accomplish this.  However that's a pretty extreme measure.

EDIT
As of Visual Studio 2017, it is now possible to change this. See the answer [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38852451/2093088)

Comment: boo!  I know it isn't your fault, but it is really annoying to have vastly different IDE behaviour based on the current language.

Comment: Might be an extreme measure but it would be awesome.

Comment: this is very very annoing!

Comment: Get used to use TAB instead of ENTER

Comment: @Vinicius NEVER!

Comment: This is very annoying to hear. I do wish they could let you change the key, especially given how every other IDE I've ever used has used enter for that functionality. What's also annoying is that enter can be arbitrarily used for some items in the menu, but not others, which is both strange and annoying.

Comment: you can use ctrl+enter to get the desired effect, but that still doesn't really solve the problem

Comment: If someone is interested, I've updated my answer talking about Visual Studio 2017 and this behavior.

Comment: Please correct this answer for vs 2017 like  Abdelilah El Aissaoui said, or remove it please. Thanks

Answer (score 124):

**UPDATE VISUAL STUDIO 2017:**

Now with Visual Studio 2017 you can change it. Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> Basic -> IntelliSense.
In *Enter key behavior* select *Never add new line on enter*

**ANSWER FOR VISUAL STUDIO 2015 AND PREVIOUS:**

If you want to avoid inserting new line on enter with autocomplete suggestion, just don't press enter. Instead of Enter press Space bar which completes your autofill and just inserts a space.

Or you may use this third party app:

[Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) makes it possible overriding Visual Studio intellisense and using its own intellisense. It is the only way I've found.
It has a 30 days free trial if you want to test it.

Comment: Probably the answer most are looking for but for me it only sort of works as wanted.  It doesn't allow for Enter to act just like the Tab to complete inline (like I'm used to from other editors).  It allows Enter to act as a completion selector only after down-arrowing into the list.  Now adapting to Tab instead.

Comment: @juanitogan I don't work with visual studio anymore but I think that there was an option to fix your problem. I am afraid I can't remember which options is.

Comment: Thanks, this has been a real annoyance, especially when moving between IDEs (Android Studio for example)