# Prevent newline while using VB.net auto-complete with intellisense

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, newline, intellisense

In Visual Studio 2010, I am writing a project in VB. I am used to writing in C# and I am getting frustrated with how when you press enter to autocomplete the intelisense suggested word it goes to a newline. In c# it stays on the same line. How can I make VB do that?

Here is a video better explaining my problem:http://youtu.be/fjL8OywIpug

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not possible to get the C# behaviour:
 [VB.NET IntelliSense : Disable newline on ENTER autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977333/vb-net-intellisense-disable-newline-on-enter-autocomplete)

- You could press space instead (you have to remove the redundant white-space afterwards)
- or you could press <kbd>Ctrl + Enter</kbd>

Comment: Not sure how i managed to make Ctrl+Enter not work, I am reduced to Tab. I'm so glad I don't use VB every day.

Comment: I use '.' (<- dot) when I know I want to go deeper into a nested object. (Also I refuse to accept this answer just yet - I don't want to be forced into bad VB-Coder habits. ;P )

Comment: Now I do and I will install VS2017 to make it work. =) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977333/vb-net-intellisense-disable-newline-on-enter-autocomplete