# How to disable new line inserting after intellisence suggestion

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, text-editor

I want to be able to type auto-property without such effect (inserting new line after I type `;`):

---

[image]

---

This only occurs if intellisence shows its suggestions. Pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> just before pressing <kbd>;</kbd> helps (suggestion popup disappears and new line is not inserted), but it seems impossible to remember, I constantly fail.

Is there a way to remove that weird *"new line"* behavior? I don't remember such in previous VS.

Comment: Maybe [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977333/vb-net-intellisense-disable-newline-on-enter-autocomplete) you can find what you're looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

1. Type: prop
2. Press tab 2 times
3. Change property type if needed
4. Press tab
5. Enter property name

You are done!