# In Visual Studio 2019, how can I configure the VB.NET code editor's IntelliSense not to insert a newline when I press enter?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Steps I took:

1. Start typing some code element, e.g. `SqlDataR`
2. Press enter to accept IntelliSense's suggestion of `SqlDataReader`

Oh no! I got a newline! This doesn't happen in the C# editor... how can I configure the VB.NET editor to behave like the C# editor and not insert a newline when I do this? Otherwise I'll have to retrain myself to accept suggestions using tab instead of enter...

Comment: Press `space` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an answer to that question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977333/vb-net-intellisense-disable-newline-on-enter-autocomplete) but it looks like it requires you to download a paid plugin

Comment: Thanks! Actually it looks like there is such an option since VS2017, so I set that option (Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> Basic -> IntelliSense -> Enter key behavior).